# Bug in set StatusBar Style in iOS 10.1 Xamarin(iOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, styles, uistatusbar

I am struggling last 30 Mintues to change the StatusBar Style to Dark so that. My Text and Icon are display as White. I try lots of thing But nothing is work for me.

**Problem Image :**

[image]

**What I have tried :**

**1.** In the `AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching()` file add the following way

`UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle,LightContent, false);`

**2.** Add below code in `ViewdidLoad` method

`NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;`

**3.** change the `info.plist`.

But nothing is Help for me.

Any Help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set Status bar style to "Light"

[image]

2. Select plist source and add key-value pair i.e "View controller-based status bar appearance" -> "No"

[image]

Comment: ya I find it but Thanks for your Answer.